# PR Canadian working remotely to a US company

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, payment, working-abroad

I am a Permanent Resident in Canada doing remote work for a company in the US. How would I get paid, and what are the required documents from me and from the company in the US so all can be legal?

Appreciate your reply and guidance. Thank you.

Comment: How you get paid depends on the arrangement. Are you an employee or a contractor, for instance? You ought to know this before starting working for anybody. Also, if you are asking about taxes, you should also mention your citizenship, if it has any bearing on your tax situation.

Answer (score 1):

This has two answers. One is when you are a US citizen. I know little of that. In this case, the US wants to tax you despite you are not in the country irregardless of who you are working for. Beyond that, I do not know.

Now ,if you are a citizen of some other country than the US (you can be Canadian or Hungarian like me or dual citizen like me in a month, doesn't matter) then you can't be an employee of a US company unless you get hold of a work visa which is really hard. So you are likely to be a contractor. There's a an entire legal minefield here where the CRA might treat you an employee vs being self employed . I will point you to http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/rc4110/README.html and not dwell on this. I am not your lawyer or accountant. Be sure to get one of each.

Comment: If the company has a Canadian office, it would be simpler for the company to manage and play you from there, and for that office to put you on assignment to the American office. I did that in reverse for years, working with a Canadian team but being officially based here in the States.

Comment: Of course. I have been employed by the subsidiary of a USA corporation in Canada before but that's tax wise for me was the same as being employed by a Canadian owned company. That's not really where the dragons are.

Comment: Granted; just suggesting a possible way to avoid dragons in case folks weren't aware of it.